# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n {2n \choose n}}{3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Does the series converge absolute, converge conditionally, or diverge.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n {2n \choose n}}{3^n}$$

I am confuse because doesnt $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{2n \choose n}}{3^n}=0$$?  Why doesnt this converge condiitonally at least and maybe absolutely?  Key says it diverges.

Comment: Why don't you try the ratio test? It easily shows that the series diverges.

Comment: Also nth term tending to $0$ is a necessary but _not_ sufficient condition for convergence. So you can't decide just by the limit of nth term. In this case however the nth term diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 4):

The [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) satisfies $\dbinom{2n}{n} \sim \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Hence, $\dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{3^n} \sim \dfrac{(4/3)^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ as $n \to \infty$, and thus, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{3^n} = \infty$. So the series diverges.

Comment: How do you know it is $\approx \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ if you dont memorize it? if series was $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n {2n \choose n}}{5^n}$$ then it converges.  I want to know because i wont remember this asymptote, also what if it is like ${3n \choose n}$?

Comment: A simpler bound is $\binom{2n}{n} \ge \frac{4^n}{2n+1}$. This is easily derived by noting that $\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{n}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n-1}+\binom{2n}{2n} = 2^{2n} = 4^n$ and that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the largest of those $2n+1$ binomial coefficients. The bound I used can be derived via [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).